# Syntax for submitting a qsub job without an actual job file?

Tags: python, sungridengine, qsub, pbs

I would like to submit qsub jobs on the fly without creating discrete job files. So, let's say I have a python script called "get_time.py" that simply reports the time. Instead of making a submission script like this:

```
cat>job.sub<<eof
    #PBS -l walltime=1:00:00
    cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
    get_time.py
eof
```

...and then submitting the job: `qsub job.sub`

I would like to be able to bypass the file creation step, and I'd image the construct would be something like this:
    `qsub -d . -e get_time.py`

where `-e` is my imaginary parameter that tells qsub that the following is code to be sent to the scheduler, instead of using a discrete submission file.

Am I crazy? It seems like there should already be a simple solution for this, but I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the name of any executable script/file to `qsub` after you've provided all your options (`-d .`, etc.). Any arguments that come after the script name are treated as arguments for that script. For example, if I had the script test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sys import argv
script, param = argv
print param
```

Then I can run

```
qsub test.py 2
```

and the output to my log will be `2`.

Two important things to note:

1. Your Python script must be executable (e.g. `chmod +x test.py`).
2. Your Python script must have a shebang (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python`).

Comment: This is what I thought. However, I have a python script which has permissions -rwxr-xr-x and the shebang line 
`#!/usr/bin/env python2.7` and qsub fails for `qsub -N test_script -o logs -e logs -V -cwd /path/to/script.py`. How do I fix this?

Comment: yeah, doesn't work for me either on OGS/GE 2011.11p1

Answer (score 4):

If you are ok with writing your job in a HERE document, as in your example, you can pass that HERE doc directly to qsub without a temporary file:

```
qsub <<eof
    #PBS -l walltime=1:00:00
    cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR
    get_time.py
eof
```

Also note that you need to escape the dollar sign in `$PBS_O_WORKDIR` or else it will be interpolated before submitting the job and end up as an empty string.

Comment: any idea how to pass script arguments this way as well? If I do `qsub $arg1 <<eof`, I get an error since qsub tries to evaluate `arg1` as if it were the input file, and the `-` syntax does not work e.g. `qsub - $arg1 <<eof`

Comment: You can put any code you like into the HERE document. Just put arg1 after get_time.py.

Comment: Right but that does not work for qsub specific items like `$NSLOTS` which do no exist until after qsub has run; it gets evaluated to an empty string by the heredoc. However I got around this by escaping it within the heredoc; `\$NSLOTS`. You can also escape the file string to prevent all expansion e.g. `<<"EOF"`. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: Yes, that's correct, any variables inside the heredoc will be interpolated before submission, not after, unless you escape them as you have described. (Actually, I should edit my answer to reflect that.)

Answer (score 3):

In grid engine, -b y specifies that the thing to be executed is a binary, not a script:

```
qsub -b y get_time.py
```

Comment: This is true only for the Sun Grid Engine I believe. The `-b` option means something else in TOURQUE clusters. See the qsub man page for more details [link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/qsub-torque)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question but...

```
echo 'date' | qsub
```

is not working well for you?

Answer (score 0):

Provided `get_time.py` is executable, and the shebang is correct, you should be able to simply run

```
qsub -d . get_time.py
```

If that fails for either reason, you can use the following construct

```
qsub -d . <<< "python get_time.py"
```

Comment: The PBS version `PBSPro_12.1.1.131502` does nit seem to know the `-d` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest for me is to add the command(s) I want to run in an `echo`-statement and pipe it to `qsub`. For example, in this case:

```
echo "get_time.py" | qsub -d . -l walltime=1:00:00
```